# Wrapping My Head Around Foreign Keys

Tags: python, django

I've already posted one question about the same project, so hopefully this isn't annoying, but I really need to make sure I know what I'm doing with ForeignKey so I don't (a) avoid it or (b) develop bad habits.

I'm working on a workout game where each user has their own account. The game is divided into various "weeks", with each week having various benchmarks that a user must meet before being able to move on to the next week. Here is an example of how I model the weeks:

```
class WeekOne(models.Model):
    # Required benchmarks for given exercises 
    squatBenchmark = 1000
    lungBenchmark = 250
    stairDaysCountBenchmark = 3
    squats = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    lunges = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    skipStairs = models.BooleanField()
    stairDaysCount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    # Set to true if benchmarks reached. 
    weekOneComplete = models.BooleanField()
```

Now, I want each user to have their own squats, lunges, skipStairs, etc. field, so I thought the way to do that would be to create a `ForeignKey` field within the UserProfile (extension of User) model, like so:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    weekOne = models.ForeignKey(WeekOne)

    def checkUpdates(self):
        if self.WeekOne.squats >= WeekOne.squatBenchmark and \
            self.WeekOne.lunges >= WeekOne.lungBenchmark and \
            self.WeekOne.stairsDayCount >= WeekOne.stairDaysCountBenchmark and \
            self.WeekOne.skipStairs:
                self.WeekOne.weekOneComplete = True
                self.save()
                self.WeekOne.save()
```

This doesn't seem to be working. I've created a view where I pass a context of this model to a template, like so:

```
def workout1(request):
    user = UserProfile(user=request.user)
    template = "workout1.html"
    context = {'user': user}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

but when I try to display `user.weekOne.squats` in my template, I get a DoesNotExist error. Also, I want to be able to display the `WeekOne` "static" variables like squatBenchmark, but `WeekOne.squats` is not recognized in my Django template either. Can anyone give me any insight on whether I am using ForeignKeys correctly and where I'm going wrong in trying to use them in my views and templates?

Comment: Can a user have more than one weekOne ? If not maybe you should change the `ForeignKey` to `OneToOneField` OR use it like  `user.weekOne_set[0].squats` , I am not sure about the syntax though.

Comment: No, WeekOne has constants as the benchmarks, but the things like the squats, lunges, skipStairs fields are all modifiable depending on what data the user enters.

Comment: you didn't read my answer for your question yesterday. I put there on how to access data for user. You totally modify the check_updates. Your not following instructions.

Comment: @cat: I did read your answer and it helped me wrap my head around some things, but I didn't realize that I had to use the `save()` function to simply access the data before any modifications, which appears to be my problem here (see answer below). I was simply trying to access the already existing data to place in a template. I used your exact instructions for data access except I forgot the saves, and I think that's where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere you refer to `self.WeekOne` I think you are meaning to refer to `self.weekOne`

weekOne is the instance variable. UserProfile instances have no such attributes WeekOne.

Standard Python naming conventions would suggest that you use `week_one` as the attribute name. Rewriting checkUpdates for you...

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
```

user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        week_one = models.ForeignKey(WeekOne)

```
    def check_updates(self):
        if (self.week_one.squats >= WeekOne.squatBenchmark and
            self.week_one.lunges >= WeekOne.lungBenchmark and
            self.week_one.stairs_day_count >= WeekOne.stair_days_count_benchmark and
            self.week_one.skip_stairs):
                self.week_one.week_one_complete = True
                self.save()
                self.week_one.save()
```

In your view code you are creating a UserProfile object but you are never saving it. You probably don't want to create a new user profile everytime a request comes in though. Django has some builtin mechanisms for creating a userprofile automatically.  Also, you are never creating a WeekOne instance. Something like

```
profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)
week_one = WeekOne()
week_one.save()
profile.week_one = week_one
profile.save()
```

There you are creating a profile for a user, creating the instance of WeekOne, adding it to the profile, and saving both of them to the database.

Comment: Good catch, thank you. But I'm still running into the main problem that I can't get past, that is, when I declare `user = UserProfile(user=request.user)`, pass user as a context into my template, and call `user.week_one.squats` or `user.squats`, I either get a DoesNotExist error or the page does not show the squat data. Also, do Python naming conventions really call for the use of underscores in every variable name, or just when the name refers to a class? I've seen tons of code that uses camelCase as its main convention, though Django seems to prefer underscores.

Comment: Yup, you can find old code (I'm looking at you twisted) that uses camelCase. But you won't find any new code. Variables/attributes are underscored. Class names are CamelCase. Pep8 lays it all out: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions Hang, on I'll edit my answer for the rest of your questions

Comment: Oh and I'm not meaning to be douchey about the style conventions. Python has really strong style conventions and everyone uses them so you may as well just jump aboard the wagon.

Comment: Finally! That works. But will this clear a user's pre-existing `WeekOne`s every time the view is loaded? Should I add something like `if UserProfile.objects.filter(user=requests.user)` and not instantiate a new WeekOne() for the user if it evaluates to true?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what you need to do. The Django Orm even has a `get_or_create` method which you can Google for.